# What is the derivative of the integral of a function?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Is this correct ?

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_0^t \phi(t)dt \right) = \phi(t)
$$

If not, how can I recover $$ \phi(t) $$ knowing only $$ \int_0^t \phi(t)dt $$ ?

Comment: [Correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: I assume $\int\limits_0^t\phi(t)dt$ means $\int\limits_0^t\phi(x)dx$ and not $\int\limits_0^t\phi(t)dx$, but you may want to clarify that.

Comment: @regret I assume you mean "not $\int ... \mathbf{dt}$"..

Comment: Quick question: is $\int_0^t\phi(t)\mathrm dt$ the same as $\int_0^t\phi(x)\mathrm dx$? It seems it indeed turns out to be the same, after an application of the foundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Peter: It works either way. I meant to show the two possibilities for what the integral might mean, not refer to the original, ambiguous integral.

Comment: @rubik: The problem with the first integral you have there is that the meaning of it is ambiguous. The middle $t$ could either be the same $t$ as the upper bound: $\int_0^T\phi(T)dt$ or it might not be: $\int_0^T\phi(t)dt$. If you do take $\int_0^t\phi(t)dt$ to actually mean $\int_0^T\phi(t)dt$, then yes, it is equivalent to $\int_0^T\phi(x)dx$.

Answer (score 4):

The expression $\int_{0}^{t}\phi\left(t\right){\rm d}t$ makes no
sense to me. It cannot be that $t$ is a variable and a constant at
the same time. I presume that you mean $\int_{0}^{t}\phi\left(x\right){\rm d}x$

For $t>0$ prescribe $\phi(t)$ by $t\mapsto 0$ if $t\neq 1$ and $t\mapsto c$ otherwise, where $c$ is some constant.

Then $\Phi\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{t}\phi\left(x\right){\rm d}x=0$ for
each $t$ so that $\Phi'\left(t\right)=0$ for each $t$.

However,
if $c\neq0$ then $\Phi'\left(1\right)=0\neq c=\phi\left(1\right)$.

This can be done with every $c$ so apparantly $\phi(1)$ cannot be recovered.
Things get better if you demand $\phi(t)$ to be continuous.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the following problem: I used the previous formula to calculate $$\phi(t)$$ in the following way:
$$ \phi(t) = \frac {1}{2T-T} \left(\int_0^{2T} \phi(t)dt - \int_0^{T} \phi(t)dt \right) (1)$$, but if I use for example $$\phi(t) = t^{3}$$, this is not correct. I expect (1) to yield the value of $$\phi(t)$$ in t = (2T+T)/2 = 1.5T, but this is not the case. 
($$\phi(t))$$ in $$t = 1.5T$$ yields $$3.375T^{3}$$ and (1) yields $$3.75T^{3} $$
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I actually seen this (uncomfortable) notation in literature. Yes, it is annoying, but it just means that t is overloaded to mean both the integration constant and the integration limit (whereas you'd treat them as "different" t's). For some reason this became conventional in some analysis books.

Comment: Sorry Alex, but it goes to far to handle this new question in a comment. Why don't you post it as a question? Btw, in (1) LHS is function in $t$ and RHS is function in $T$. Quite strange.

Comment: @ShaiDeshe Thank you for your information. In books allready... (sigh). Bad development!

Comment: @drhab  OK, I posted my previous comment in this new [Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091717/practical-calculation-of-the-derivative-of-the-integral-of-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

(i) No, it is not correct. You probably mean 
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} \left( \int_0^t \phi(x) \, \text{d}x \right) = \phi(t)
.$$

This  equality is also known as the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Part 1.

(ii) You can recover $\phi (t)$ by differentiating, as demonstrated above.

Comment: The expression on the left seems to be a function while the one on the right is a number.

Comment: The function $f(t) = \int_0^t \phi(x) \, \text{d}x$ is also known as the *area-so-far* function, and gives the net area under $\phi(x)$ from a fixed point. The equality is correct, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.

Comment: I would say $\phi$ is a function and $\phi(t)$ is the value of $\phi$ at $t$: a number, while $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)$ is the derivative function of $f$: a function. Wouldn't you?

Comment: Either are acceptable. Most would agree that $f(x)=x$ is a *function*. The $()$ represents functional notation, and denotes that the value of $f(x)$ is determined by $x$.

Comment: Well now you have lost me. I would say that $f(x) = x$ is an equation, which defines a function $f$.

Comment: How would you prefer the notation then? Most won't argue with the statement, let $f(x) = x$ be the identity **function**. Almost every Calculus textbook uses the same notation as I have in (i) to explain FTC1.

Comment: I think if the right side of your equation had $\phi$ in place of $\phi(t)$, it would be more clear. The derivative of the function $f$ defined by $f(t)=\int_0^t\phi$ is equal to $\phi$, in other words, $f'=\phi$.

Comment: I feel that is sloppy notation. It is an important distinction that $\phi$ is a function of $x$, where as $f$ is a function of $t$ on the left hand side. Then, in differentiation, we get $\phi$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: I think there is, in addition to a small disagreement, a grand miscommunication at play here. I will leave you with the words: I am mostly nitpicking, sorry.

Comment: No problem! It's good to be careful with our notation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Phi$ the antiderivative of $\phi$ ($\Phi'(t)=\phi(t)$) such as $\Phi(0)=0$

We have $\Phi(t)=\int_0^t \phi(t)dt$ thus $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^t \phi(t)dt\right)=\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}=\phi(t)$