# Practical calculation of the derivative of the integral of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091653/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-integral-of-a-function), I wanted to make sure that 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_0^{t} \phi(t)dt \right) = \phi(t),$$ and provided $\phi(t)$ is continuous, and that a derivative of the function exists, it was shown in that [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091653/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-integral-of-a-function) that a function $\phi(t)$ can be recovered in that way.

However, I still have the following problem: I used the previous formula to calculate $\phi(t)$ in the following way:
$$ \phi(t) \bigg|_{t=1.5T}= \frac {1}{2T-T} \left(\int_0^{2T} \phi(t)dt - \int_0^{T} \phi(t)dt \right) (1)$$ but if I use for example $$\phi(t) = t^{3},$$ this is not correct. I expect (1) to yield the value of $\phi(t)$ in t = (2T+T)/2 = 1.5T, but this is not the case. 
$\phi(t) \bigg|_{t=1.5T}$ yields $3.375T^{3}$ and (1) yields $3.75T^{3} $.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand at all how you used the previous formula to arrive at expression (1). The formula says to take a derivative of the integral, whereas you have something totally different.

Comment: @Alex R.    $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{v(t+\epsilon)-v(t)}{\epsilon} $  so I took the difference of $\int_0^t \phi(t)dt$ on 2 time intervals, and I normalized the result by the difference in time between the 2 time intervals.